# JAX-RS DynamicFilter not being called for sub-resource

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, cxf

According to the documentation it should be possible to use [`DynamicFeature`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/DynamicFeature.html) for resources and sub-resources. As an effect I expect to have filter registered and called whenever sub-resource endpoint is being called - ie `GET /some/sub/x`. However following is not working for me (nor other similar approaches):

- annotation

  ```java
  @NameBinding
  @Target({METHOD, TYPE})
  @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
  public @interface SomeFilterAnn {}
  ```
- resource

  ```java
  @SomeFilterAnn
  @Path("/some")
  public class SomeResource {
    @GET
    public String getSome() {
      return "some";
    }

    @Path("/sub")
    public SubResource getSub() {
      return new SubResource();
    }

    @SomeFilterAnn
    @Path("/x")
    public static class SubResource {
      @GET
      public String getSome() {
        return "sub";
      }
    }
  }
  ```
- filter (it is actually more complex and configured by `DynamicFilter`)

  ```java
  @SomeFilterAnn
  public class SomeFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SomeFilter.class);

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
      LOG.info("filter called");
    }
  }
  ```
- here is `DynamicFeature` that I'd like to register filter for resource and sub-resource. Actually I would expect that `configure()` would be called also for `SubResource` so `resourceInfo.getResourceClass() == SubResource.class` but cannot manage to achieve this.

  ```java
  @Provider
  public class SomeDynamicFeature implements DynamicFeature {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SomeDynamicFeature.class);

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceInfo resourceInfo, FeatureContext context) {
      Class<?> resourceClass = resourceInfo.getResourceClass();

      // this works
      if (resourceClass == SomeResource.class) {
        LOG.info("register resource filter");
        context.register(new SomeFilter(/*some config*/));
      }

      // this does not work (not called for Subresource)
      if (resourceClass == SomeResource.SubResource.class) {
        LOG.info("register resource filter");
        context.register(new SomeFilter(/*some config*/));
      }

      // this also does not work (filter not called for Subresource)
      if (resourceInfo.getResourceMethod().getReturnType() == SomeResource.SubResource.class) {
        LOG.info("register subresource filter");
        context.register(new SomeFilter(/*some config*/));
      }
    }
  }
  ```

I'm running this on WildFly 8.2 with CXF and without Jersey or RESTEasy

**EDIT**

I have found that annotating `SomeFilter` with `@Provider` allows filter to works without need of `DynamicFeature` however I don't know then how to configure my filter - here is [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33329853/how-can-i-provide-configuration-to-jax-rs-provider-annotated-containerrequestfi) about it.

Comment: Try with `Method.getDeclaringClass()`. The resource method will never the locator, so your last `if` is useless. And I guess the resource class is always be the parent resource, that's why the second is never called. But the resource method _can_ be in the sub resource, so check the declaring class of the method should work. Just a theory.

Comment: I would expect that  `resourceInfo.getResourceMethod().getDeclaringClass() == resourceInfo.getResourceClass()`. Actually I was logging all the invocations of DynamicFeature.configure() and there is no invocation for `SubResource` class.