# How can I provide configuration to JAX-RS @Provider annotated ContainerRequestFilter?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, cxf

I'm using `ContainerRequestFilter` filter like this:

```java
@NameBinding
@Target({TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface SomeFilterAnn {}

@SomeFilterAnn
@Provider
public class SomeFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SomeFilter.class);

  @Override
  public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
    // ...
  }
}
```

It makes possible to bind the filter to rest resources by `@SomeFilterAnn` automatically. This works also for sub-resources in opposite to `DynamicFeature` issue described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33323754/jax-rs-dynamicfilter-not-being-called-for-sub-resource).

I need however to do some advanced configuration to my `SomeFilter` and wonder what is the jax-rs way to do it - ie. use `@Context`/`@Provider` or some CXF or WildFly 8.2 mechanism (but no RESTEasy nor Jersey) or other way to provide access to configuration logic.